# Can't get Google Maps api v3 to display markers from xml file

Tags: google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing

I should have on my hands what is proper working JS and an xml file...I'm simply trying to take advantage of the huge database of locations that has been offered up as free for everyone to use - located @ http://www.craftbeer.com/breweries/brewery-locator/find-a-us-brewery

I'm tried using their maps.js and xml file...but all I end up with is a blank maps screen...

Here is the Javascript...

```
/*********************************************

**Google Maps Custom API work**

This code can be reused on any site to display a local map of breweries from our local iMis dump, as well as pull in beermapping.

Hey! Don't forget to include API in functions.php! Function is conditionally initialized in footer.php

*/  

//Set up variables to create marker
var gmarkers = [];
var mapMarkers = [];
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
var icon = 'http://www.craftbeer.com/wp-content/uploads/marker.png';

//Initialize Map
function view_map(xml_file, latitude, longitude, varZoom) { 
        console.log('view map');
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), { //Create the map, Set Default Zoom level and type

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
            zoom: varZoom,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false
        });


//-- Listeners --//
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
   console.log('center changed');
   //clearMarkers();    
  });

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
    //this part runs when the mapobject is created and rendered
    console.log("loaded");
    $("#loading-screen").fadeOut(250, function(){});
    $("#loading-icon").fadeOut();
    //google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){   });
}); 


//console.log(xml_file);
var download_file = xml_file; //this variable is passed in so we can re-use this script

//Pull in the XML feed
downloadUrl(download_file, function(data) { 
    console.log("downloading xml");
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");


    //Loop through all markers in the XML file
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var state = markers[i].getAttribute("state");
        var x   = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
        var y   = markers[i].getAttribute("lng");

        if ( state != 'PR' && state != 'VI' &&  state != 'GU' && x != "" ){
        //console.log(state);

        var ids = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("id"));

        var z = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y,i);
        //console.log(x);

        var _id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("company");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var city = markers[i].getAttribute("city");

        var zip = markers[i].getAttribute("zip");
        var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
        var url = markers[i].getAttribute("url");
        var brewery_type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var member_type = '';
        var member_type = markers[i].getAttribute("member_type");
        var offer =  markers[i].getAttribute("offer");


        var html = "<div class='bubble_content'><strong>" + name + "</strong><br />";
        html += address + "<br/>" + city + ", " + state + " " + zip;
        if(url) html += "<br /><br /><a href='http://" + url + "' target='_blank'>Visit Web Site</a></div>";


        //var marker = createMarker(ids, z, title, contentstring);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: z,  
            map: map,
            title: name,
            icon: icon,
            html: html,
            zindex: i
        });

        //Add a listener for every icon click
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map,this);
            //map.setZoom(10);
            //map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
            console.log(this);
        });   

        gmarkers[ids] = marker;
        mapMarkers.push(marker);

        if( x && y ){
            //console.log(ids);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html});
        }
       /* google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            console.log('marker clicked');

          });
        */
        //bounds.extend(z);
        //map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }//end check for US states only!        
    } //end for loop


    var mcOptions = {gridSize: 60, maxZoom: 9};
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, mapMarkers, mcOptions); //this is the function that groups the icons into markers


    });
} //End full function to create map

/*
* FUNCTION
*
* click to bring up one icon when clicked from the list.
*/
function myclick(i){
    console.log('clicked a title ' + i);    
    smoothScroll("#primary");   

    var lat = parseFloat(gmarkers[i].position.k);
    var lng = parseFloat(gmarkers[i].position.B);

    console.log(lat);

    map.setCenter({lat: lat, lng: lng});
    map.setZoom(13);
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
};


function createMarker(ids, z, title, contentstring){
    console.log('createMarker');
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: z,  
        map: map,
        title: title,
        html: contentstring,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });   

    gmarkers[ids] = marker;
    //console.log(gmarkers[ids]);

};

/*
* FUNCTION findAddress()
*
* given an adress string, zoom the map to the proper state
*/

function findAddress(position) {

    //Let's determind if we have a state (address) or LatLng
    var addressStr = $("#state_select li.active").data('state-id'); 
    if (addressStr != 'Select a State') address = "US State of "+addressStr;

    if(position) {
        var lat = parseFloat(position['latitude']);
        var lng = parseFloat(position['longitude']);
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        //console.log(latlng);
    }

    //Now let's geocode - two different cases
    if (geocoder && position) { //If LatLng
        //console.log('near me');
        geocoder.geocode( { 'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                    if (results && results[0] && results[0].geometry && results[0].geometry.viewport && addressStr!="ON" && addressStr!="INT") {
                        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport); //resize map to fit. 
                        map.setZoom(13);
                    }       
                } else {
                    alert("No results found");
                }   
            }
        });       
     } else if (geocoder && address!="") { //If State
        //console.log('by state');
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                    if (results && results[0] && results[0].geometry && results[0].geometry.viewport && addressStr!="ON" && addressStr!="INT") {
                        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport); //resize map to fit. 
                        map.setZoom(6);
                    }       
                } else {
                    alert("No results found");
                }
            }          
        });
    } else {
        //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
}


function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}





function doNothing() {}
```

And here is the link to the xml file....
http://www.straighttothepint.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-google-maps/Google_Map_APIs.xml

I've spent days doing google searches and testing different sections of code to at least get a basic google map to show up via the xml file markers...but to no avail - Any help would be tremendously appreciated!!
~Cheers

**EDIT:**
Everything worked as expected once I included the following script inline on the page prior to calling the maps.js file. Thanks everyone!

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){ 

var latitude = 39.300299;
var longitude = -97.382812;
view_map('./uploads/your_xml_file.xml', latitude,longitude,4);
//scripts to handle mapping are in js/mylibs/map.js.php              
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Create a JS Fiddle for your code and Ill take a look

Comment: Thanks much loanburger :) - But from what I've read, jsfiddle can't call xml files cross-domain to pull in the info properly... Closest I've seen was this work-around: http://jsfiddle.net/ee9mhmoe/

Comment: Just copy a snipit of the xml for a few markers and add it to a string variable in the fiddle and use that.

Comment: [Your code works as is](http://jsfiddle.net/wj2nbt0x/) (although there are places that use undocumented properties of the API which will cause it to break. Your xml has the MIME type "application/xml".  The issue is outside of what you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to jump in and help out geocodezip! While I'm relieved that the code itself seems to be intact....for the life of me I can't figure out what else could be causing the display issue... I'll investigate the usual suspects ( css, theme, api call, etc )

Comment: Finally got the code to work! Currently it's inline and loaded in the body of the page...for some reason it wasn't rendering properly being called from the header. Thanks so much Geocode! I think i can figure it out from here :)

Comment: ^Correction - It wasn't the placement, but rather it wasn't working being called from a JS file, but inline on page it showed up just fine. Perhaps something to do with the initialize function?

Comment: And Indeed it was the initialize function, I edited the original post in case the code helps anyone else.


Thanks again for all of your help! I'm pretty new to all of this JS stuff, you saved me days worth of pulling my hair out^ :) ~Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the html and the code you provided above I constructed a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/qafsex5x/

I added two markers in an xml string at the top in the fiddle.

I basically parse the xml doing this:

```
var markers = $(xml).find("marker");
```

Its then simply the same for loop you had:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
  {
    ...
  }
```

The fiddle will show you the markers.

Comment: Thank you so much loanburger :) I'll give this version a go right now!

Comment: Well... Tried a new theme, with all css removed ( except for map css) and using the working js fiddle code and still getting a blank map. I guess i'll start disabling all my wp plugins, not sure what else would be causing this...

Comment: Disabled all plugins - still the same result...No console errors in chrome, not sure what else to try. If it helps at all here is the page: http://www.straighttothepint.com/find-brewery/

I'm fairly certain i've implemented all the required code correctly. Added custom css, called the google api and maps.js file that contains the javascript portion from the page...Am I missing something here?

Comment: Tried new version of jquery...same results ( v1.3.2 & v2.1.3)

Comment: I just woke.  I see its sorted not based on your comments above. well done.

Comment: Thanks loanburger! Yea it's finally operational thanks to you and geocode :) ~Cheers